# Login y redirección a página específica en PHP y Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html5

¿Cómo capturar el id de un usuario, que al iniciar sesión en un formulario html vaya a otra página donde sepa que es este usuario el que ha ingresado?

Estoy iniciando un proyecto, específicamente un ERP web, estoy aprendiendo y llevando a cabo lo aprendido a la vez, soy muy poco conocedor de PHP Y JS, ya que apenas empiezo, y tengo una pregunta...

En la página principal del proyecto, hay un formulario de html, en donde pedirá ingresar la contraseña y al presionar la tecla Enter, se hará una consulta a la base de datos, utilizando también Ajax para hacerlo de manera asincrónica, y si existe esta contraseña que tiene un id, mostrará en un campo de texto, el usuario con un único id el cual tiene registrada esa contraseña en la base de datos, y lo que deseo es, al mismo tiempo de presionar la tecla enter, muestre en un select de html, las empresas que tiene este usuario, y en otro select, las sucursales que tiene el mismo, las empresas y las sucursales están en tablas distintas dentro de la base de datos, entonces al dar enter y consultar si existe la contraseña, mostrará el usuario que tiene el id, pero que a su vez, se consulte las empresas y sucursales que tiene este usuario, pero según su id, y los muestre en pantalla en su respectivo lugar, y ahora el detalle más específico...

Luego de mostrar en pantalla todos los datos, es porque la contraseña, el usuario, la empresa y la sucursal que seleccionó, existen, entonces, al dar click en el botón ingresar, irá a otra pantalla totalmente diferente, es decir, ya el menú principal del ERP pero, **¿cómo saber qué usuario es el que ingresó?** tanto como para llenar la empresa y la sucursal, como para mostrar los datos ya dentro del programa, porque no puede aparecer los datos de un usuario "1" por poner un ejemplo, a un usuario "2", a cada usuario le tiene que aparecer únicamente sus datos. ¿Cómo se puede hacer en php, html y js esto amigos? que se sepa qué usuario es el que ingresó, no sé si sería creando variables y dejarla en memoria en cada una de las páginas, o de qué forma llamar al id de cada usuario para que se muestre sus datos e información en cualquiera de las ventanas o páginas del ERP que esté, una vez ya haya ingresado, y no estarle pidiendo contraseña, empresa, etc, en cada una de ellas.

Esto no sólo lo necesito específicamente en mi código actual, si no que, de manera general, cuál sería la lógica para esto. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Adjunto mi código html por si sirve de ayuda:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="inicio.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <title>Gestión 2022</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="divarriba">

       <h5>SDIG</h5>
       <h6>Gestión</h6>

       <div class="icon2 icon-key"></div>

       <h1>Gestión Web</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="esquina"></div>

    <table class="ingresardatos">
        <tr>
<form method="POST">
    <td><h2 class="contraseña">Contraseña:</h2></td> <td class="td"><input class="boxcontraseña" id="contraseña" type="text" name="contraseña" autocomplete="off" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><h2 class="usuario">Usuario:</h2></td> <td><input type="text" class="boxusuario" id="usuario" name="usuario" value=""></td>
    </tr>

            <td><h2 class="empresa">Empresa:</h2></td>
            <td><select name="empresa" id="empresa" value="" style="width:98%; height:calc(1.2em + 1.2vw);" >

                <option value="0"></option>
        
                </select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><h2 class="sucursal">Sucursal:</h2></td>
            <td><select name="sucursal" id="sucursal" style="width:98%; height:calc(1.2em + 1.2vw);" >

                <option value="0"></option>
                
                </select></td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
<div id="Oculto"></div>
<script>
$("input[name='contraseña']").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $.post('ingresar.php', {
            contraseña : $("input[name='contraseña']").val()
        }, function(data){
            $('#Oculto').html(data);
        });
    }
});
</script>
<?php
    include ("ingresar.php");
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Y mi código php:

```
<?php

$conex = mysqli_connect("SERVIDOR", "USUARIO", "CONTRASEÑA", "BASE DE DATOS");
if ($conex->connect_error) {
    die('<p>Failed to connect to MySQL: '. $conex->connect_error .'</p>');
  } else {
    echo '<p>Connection to MySQL server successfully established.</p>';
  }
?>

<script>
    $("input[name='usuario']").val('');
</script>
<?php

$contraseña = (is_numeric($_POST['contraseña']))?$_POST['contraseña']:NULL;
if(!is_null($contraseña)){
    $consulta = 'SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE contraseña= '.$contraseña.';';
    $fila = $conex->query($consulta);
    $registro = $fila->fetch_assoc();
    $totalfilas = $conex->affected_rows;
    if($totalfilas == 0){
        echo "<script>alert('No hay valores que coincidan con la búsqueda.');</script>";
    } else {
        ?>
        <script>
            $("input[name='usuario']").val("<?php echo $registro['usuario'];?>");    
        </script>
<?php
    }
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Estás metiendo un valor no numérico');</script>";
}
?>
```

Y por último adjunto una fotografía de esta pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para tener acceso a los datos del usuario cuando inicia sesión, necesitarás exactamente eso, manejar la sesión del usuario. Puedes implementarlo desde cero, si quieres, pero la mayoría de web frameworks ya incluyen esquemas de autenticación/autorización que puedes utilizar para lograr lo que deseas. Son soluciones estandarizadas, evaluadas y probadas por cientos de miles de personas. Estás utilizando algún framework php?

Comment: Necesitas saber [Sesiones](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.session.php). Sugiero tomes [un curso](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=php+sesiones) del tema, ya que es algo básico del aprendizaje de PHP.

Comment: Yo diría que la lógica que estás empleando no es la mas segura. Según entiendo lo primero que uno hace es meter una contraseña, si esa contraseña existe, el mismo sistema le dice a uno cual es el usuario que la tiene. Primero, eso no es una buena practica, pues luego de meter contraseñas aleatorias se sabría que usuario tiene cuales contraseñas. Y lo segundo para saber si esa contraseña la tiene "alguien" en tu sistema, deberías tener que almacenarla en texto plano (cosa que no es para nada recomendable). Lo normal es usar un hash de la contraseña (por seguridad).

Comment: que haría el sistema si 2 usuarios tiene la misma contraseña?

Comment: @Arriel, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, realmente no, no uso ningún framework amigo, soy muy nuevo realmente en esto, ¿cómo puedo conseguir dichos frameworks? y ¿cómo puedo aplicarlos a lo que necesito? tanto para que al dar enter se llene la casilla de empresa y sucursal, como para mostrar sus datos en la siguiente página, que no se cruce con los datos de otros usuarios, si no que, se mantenga iniciada su sesión.